# angular directive is not at the right place

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have simple angular directive in the table but it renders before the table.

```js
app.directive('myDirective',function () {
  return {
    restrict : "E",
    templateUrl : "directives/myDirectiv.html",
    replace : true
  }
})
```

```html
  <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Deposit</th>
              <th>Credit Card</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <my-Directive></my-Directive>
          </tbody>
    </table>


 <!-- here is html in the directive -->

<tr>
  <td>001</td>
  <td>Danilo</td>
  <td>7163547265</td>
  <td>Visa</td>
</tr>
```

How can i fix it to be in the right place. Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `custom-element` inside `tbody` element of table. If you add custom element inside `tbody` it will consider as invalid html & that custom element will thrown out.

You should convert your directive type to restrict to `A`(attribute) instead of `E`(element). Now put your directive over `tbody` element.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective',function () {
  return {
    restrict : "A", //<-- converted E to A 
    templateUrl : "directives/myDirectiv.html",
    //replace : true //it isn't needed, though this has been deprecated since 1.5+
  }
})
```

Comment: Ty for fast answer. I see that works well with comment directive as well.

Comment: @Danilo I see with comment it would work. but people generally don't prefer to use it. Accept answer if it does helped you, Thanks :)